# Subscribe to ActiveMQ Topic using MassTransit

Tags: asp.net-core, activemq-classic, masstransit

Is there a way to subscribe to a topic, from ActiveMQ, using MassTransit's ActiveMqTransport?

I am using MassTransit as a HostedService in a Asp.Net Core Mvc project, and the following code creates a subscription to a Queue, but I can't find any parameter or configuration that allows me to subscribe to a Topic.

```
services.AddMassTransit(massTransitconfiguration =>
{
    massTransitconfiguration.AddConsumer<MyCreatedConsumer>();

    massTransitconfiguration.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingActiveMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(this.configuration["activeMqHost"]), h =>
        {
            h.Username(this.configuration["activeMqUsername"]);
            h.Password(this.configuration["activeMqPassword"]);
        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, this.configuration["activeMqTopicName"], endpointConfiguration =>
        {
            EndpointConvention.Map<MyEvent>(endpointConfiguration.InputAddress);

            endpointConfiguration.ConfigureConsumer<MyCreatedConsumer>(provider);
        });
    }));

    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusService>();
});
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent in MassTransit to this method, from Apache.NMS: http://activemq.apache.org/components/nms/msdoc/1.6.0/vs2005/Output/html/M_Apache_NMS_ISession_CreateDurableConsumer_4_a063fdcf.htm

Answer (score -1):

When configuring your receive endpoint, the name you specify is for the queue to which messages are delivered/received. Consumers configured on that receive endpoint will automatically bind to topics whose names match the message type formatted names, so that published messages (by MassTransit) will be received on that queue.

To bind a specific topic, such as one on which messages are produced by another system, or just named specifically for whatever reason, you can use the `.Bind()` method of the receive endpoint configurator. Such as:

```
e.Bind("some-topic");
```

This will add an additional binding on the receive endpoint. Consumers which handle the message types on that topic will still need to be present, or messages will be moved to the skipped queue.

Comment: The ReceiveEndpoint methods takes a queueName as its second argument. When doing e.Bind, I need pass in the same parameter? In my example it would be this.configuration["activeMqTopicName"]. Also, I am getting this exception, when doing that: "Only virtual topics can be bound".

Comment: I would have to look closer at how the ActiveMQ topology works, but I do know that receive endpoints are on queues, not topics, regardless of what you have in your configuration.

Comment: The same problem for me, the publisher send message to a topic while consumer is listening on a queue, not sure what I am missing, is there a solid sample for subscribing event via ActiveMQ?

Comment: With MassTransit? It just works, you publish, the message goes via a virtual topic to the consumer endpoint. if you send directly to the queue, that works too. This is a really, really old question so...

Comment: @Simon did you manage to solve your problem? We are having the same kind of problem and the lack of examples when masstransit are using activemq in different ways are frustrating.

Comment: @MagnusBackeus, not really, I gave up.